# Суть адаптивной верстки: по какому принципу делается?

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript, css

По принципу написания стилей почти для каждого разрешения экрана, как-то так?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
   ...
}
```

Или как? Проясните пожалуйста, как эти сайты делаются, где сжимаешь окно браузера по ширине, и оно превращается в мобильный вид.

Answer (score 1):

адаптивная верстка или респонсивный дизайн, работает почти так, но с дополнением. Он сажается на модульную сетку из 12 или 16 колонок, применяется CSS framework, кто не делел ни разу - советую скачать готовый у [960](http://960.gs/), работаем пиксель в пиксель, но я предпочитаю просто доделать сайт под маленькие экраны дополнительным CSS, при капризном клиенте, когда он говорит сколько это будет по ширине и спорит, что он так хочет, то придерживаться сетки трудно, но если вы работаете в фирме, то дизайн-студия таких посылает подальше и не связываются с ними, то да, сетка одно из лучших решений